# How do you think, will a one-core processor affects a performance of a flash game?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How do you think, will a one-core processor affects a performance of a flash game?

Comment: This question is too broad.  The power of a processor will affect the performance of a flash game, yes... but can the developer actually spawn non-ui threads to offload work to other cores or the GPU?  No.  The developer has precisely one "thread" in which to do all processing (except for Loader and URLLoader which are asynchronous operations that do not appear to be handled in the main ui thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont? Feel free to elaborate on your question as it's a bit vague.

Anyhow, flash does not support threading at all, everything is run in a single thread (with the exception of pixel bender shaders, which have their own thread).

So basically it wont, as multi core does not have any advantages for a flash/air application/game.

Now seeing how we're getting a real API for accessing the GPU, the threading issue might change in the not so distant future, especially considering that HTML5 compliant browsers can spawn threads.

Comment: "with the exception of pixel bender shaders, which have their own thread" are you sure about that?

Comment: this isn't really true, the flash player itself uses multiple threads even though they're not available for your code.

Answer (score 2):

No, but yes. Multiple threads are not available to your actionscript code ([save for pixelbender](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_pixelbender.html)). However, the flash player itself from [version 9 and especially 10 uses mulitple threads](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/features/video/multicore/) to better make use of multicore processors. So, having a multicore processor will improve general performance in your game, but there's really not much you can or need to do to take advantage of it.